# What exactly is a superior and inferior of a sequence of function?

Tags: real-analysis

I  have the following definition:

lim sup $f_n(x) = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\text{sup}\{f_k(x) : k \ge n\})$

lim inf $f_n(x) = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\text{inf}\{f_k(x) : k \ge n\})$

I understand as follows:

For each $n$ we have a set  $\{f_n,f_{n+1},f_{n+2},..., \}$ thus we have a sequence of function such that $\{f_n,f_{n+1},f_{n+2},..., \}\supset\{f_{n+1},f_{n+2},f_{n+3}..., \} \supset \{f_{n+2},f_{n+3},f_{n+4}..., \}$
here if $n \rightarrow \infty$  we have a set (that I don't know how to write) and in that set someway (explain me how to do that) we compute the infimum that should be a function; not necessarily in that set I think.

is that correct? I need help how calculate those limits, it reminds me the upper and the lower sum of a function.

Comment: Forget the functions. Basically you have a sequence, namely $a_n = f_n(x)$ and $x$ is fixed.

Comment: but in that way the limit superior (inferior) will be just a number and it should be a function.

Comment: $g(x) = \limsup f_n(x)$ is a function in $x$. But for each fixed $x$, $\limsup f_n(x)$ is a number. This is called a "pointwise definition".

Comment: Then the the limit superior (and inferior) always exists for any x ? what if it is $\pm \infty$

Comment: Then $g(x) = \infty$ or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Just as we can compute the limit of sequences of functions, we can compute the limit superior and inferior of the sequence of functions.

For every $x$ in the domain where the sequence is defined, we expect $\left\lbrace f_n \left( x \right) \right\rbrace$ to be a real sequence for which we know how to compute limit superior (and inferior).

Thus, if for a particular $x$, the limit superior of $\left\lbrace f_n \left( x \right) \right\rbrace$ is $r_x$, we get a function $f: D \rightarrow C$, where $D$ is the domain and $C$ is the codomain, as $f \left( x \right) = r_x$ which we shall call the limit superior of the sequence of functions $\left\lbrace f_n \right\rbrace$.

Similarly, we can compute limit inferior.

Comment: How do you define the $\limsup$ of a complex sequence?

Comment: I thought we can. But we really can not. I am editing the answer accordingly.